# How to fix number of rows doesn't match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for an help in order to fix error :

> The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range

```
var s = SpreadSheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var file1 = SpreadSheetApp.openById(DriveApp.getFilesByName("test1").next().getId()); // 6000 rows
var file2 = SpreadSheetApp.openById(DriveApp.getFilesByName("test2").next().getId()); // 4000 rows
var file2 = SpreadSheetApp.openById(DriveApp.getFilesByName("test2").next().getId()); // 7000 rows
var files = [file1,file2,file3];
var lastRow = 1;
for (var i = 0; i<=files.length;i++){
   var rangeSource = files[i].getRange("A:AZ").getValues();
   s.getRange("A"+lastRow+":AZ").setValues(rangeSource);
   lastRow = s.getLastRow();
}
```

I know that number of row doesn't match, but I'm looking for a tips to avoid this error, without inserting rows in source Data and without using IMPORTRANGE formula in first cell of my current Sheet.

IF someone has a solution for this type of error, it could be very nice and usefull !

I've already search issues like this but I still don't understand, examples given are too sophisticated for me because I'm newbie in coding.

Sincerely !

BigBenne

Comment: Can you share an example spreadsheet?  Do the 3 separate files have the same number of columns with data?

Comment: Does the error indicate you any codeline when you execute it? It's easier to figure out what the problem is if it does.

Comment: OneInAMillion - Yes the 3 separate files do have the same number of columns with data.

   Rodrigo Biffi - If you mean the line where this occured line 9 : ```s.getRange("A"+lastRow+":AZ").setValues(rangeSource);```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc() {
  const tsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("test1").next().getId(); // 6000 rows
  var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("test2").next().getId(); // 4000 rows
  var file3 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("test3").next().getId(); // 7000 rows
  var files = [file1, file2, file3];
  var lastRow = 1;
  files.forEach(id=>{
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    let sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
    let vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),26).getValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! I understood everything thanks to your code !
I think I'm able to re-use that next time ! 

Sincerely 
BigBenne.